# Getting second path element from url using javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

How do I do the following?

I have the following url

http://www.example.com/example/test/search

How do I get the "test" from the url using the javascript?

I would like to have a function that I call q = getUrlVars()
and when I do q[1] it should give me the "test" (or parameter after second slash) from the url.

I am new to javascript. I know regex expressions is the way to get started, but I am not sure how to use that to get what I need. Thanks!

Comment: Is this MVC? Normally a parameter in a URL would have the form ?parm=xxx&parm2=yyy.

Answer (score 11):

No need for regex's here. This should do the trick:

### When working with current url

```
var path = window.location.pathname.split("/");
// Use path[2] to get 'test'
```

### When working with any url as a string:

```
var strUrl = "http://www.example.com/example/test/search";
var path = strUrl.replace(/^https?:\/\//, '').split('/');
// Use path[2] to get 'test'
```

Note that `path` will be a zero-based `Array`, therefore you would assume going for `path[1]` would do the trick. In this case however, `path[0]` will return the first result of `.split()`, an empty string.

Comment: that doesn't work. That gets "/"

Comment: and if the url is a string, like the OP has used for an example?

Comment: the empty string at `path[0]` is not because it is a zero-based array. It's because the value at `path[0]` is empty. likely because the string being split is `"/example/test/search"`

Comment: @musefan He said: *How do I get the "test" from the url using the javascript*. Never mentioned the URL being a `string`, therefore I assumed going for `window.location.pathname` would be a good call.

Comment: yeah, get "test" from the url he provided, he didn't say he was running the script on that exact page. Though it may turn out it is the case. You should expand your answer to show both methods

Comment: console.log(window.location.pathname); gives me "/" and not http://www.example.com/example/test/search

Comment: @jewelwast which browser?

Comment: Updated answer to utilize a string URL. Is it working for you now @jewelwast?

Comment: I am saying that window.location.pathname. does not give me the current url in chrome.

Comment: @jewelwast Maybe you should be a little more specific about your setup. I'm running the latest Chrome and on this very page I've opened the console and executed `window.location.pathname`. It gave me: `/questions/15435757/getting-second-path-element-from-url-using-javascript/15435796`

Answer (score 0):

Try [URI.js](http://medialize.github.com/URI.js/). In particular, the [segment()](http://medialize.github.com/URI.js/docs.html#accessors-segment) method should give you what you need.

Comment: Voting down because a library suggestion should just be a comment. The question implied a vanilla javascript solution.